# Kendo ui empty textbox

Tags: c#, kendo-ui

I would like to have specific validation for kendo mumeric textbox.

It should be something like "amount line" [on telerik demo page](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/validator/index) with a little upgrade:
In demo can user completely delete amount. After that, if user click somewhere else, I would like to fill default value in this line - zero for example.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the past, I've leveraged the change event of the numeric text box to check for this case. Like this:

```
function onChange() {
    // If user clears, default to 0
    if (!this.value()) {
        this.value(0);
    }
}

$("#numerictextbox").kendoNumericTextBox({
    change: onChange,
    spin: onSpin
});
```

http://dojo.telerik.com/UFAHI